# Xamarin XAML binding PanGestureRecognizer to function in ViewModel [XFC0009]

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

I'm trying to bind a `PanGestureRecognizer` to a function in my ViewModel. Relevant lines below:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModels;assembly=Project">
<Image>
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="{x:Static viewmodels:ClickViewModel.PanVolume}"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

```
namespace Project.ViewModels
{
    public sealed class ClickViewModel
    {
        public static EventHandler<PanUpdatedEventArgs> PanVolume { get; } = (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Do Stuff
        };
    }
}
```

Trying to build the project gives me the following error `[XFC0009] No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "PanUpdated", or mismatching type between value and property.` Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so, how might be able to get it working right? I know I could make a function in the `view.xaml.cs` file, like `_panUpdate`. Is there a way, without binding, to specify a function in a different class? I know ICommands exist, and I'm using them for buttons, but I need the `EventArgs` (`e` parameter in the lambda) in this case, so that's why I can't just do an ICommand like I can with all the buttons.

Comment: You can’t bind event handlers.  You can bind commands

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to say that in an answer, and I'll mark it. I was wondering if that was the case, but only because of the lack of anything talking about it.

Comment: A helper to do this is XCT's [Event to Command Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior).